# Regex - capture only if group exists, if not ignore

Tags: regex

I have this regex

```
(\w+)\s*\:\s*(\W\d+)
```

set to match something like

```
"price: $200"
```

what do I need to do to change it so it will match either `"price: $200"` or `"$200"` (if the price: part doesn't exist)

I tried

```
(?:(\w+)\s*\:\s*)*(\W\d+)
```

but that doesn't work, as it gives me an empty match for the first one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

how about:

```
(\w+\s*:\s*)?(\W\d+)
```

the `?` means the group will show up 1 or 0 time. you can add your own capture group(s) for convenient data fetching.

Comment: @NickGinanto if you want a uncaptured group, you need change the first `(` -> `(?:`

Comment: I want to capture if it exists, but not capture if it doesnt

Comment: @NickGinanto then with capture group, if it is empty, then not exist, if it is not empty it exists. what's the problem?

Comment: if thats how regex should behave then ok :)

Answer (score 3):

```
(?=.*?:)(\S+)\s*:\s*(\S+)|(\S+)
```

You can use lookeahead as well.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/oO8zI4/5

Answer (score 2):

Make first part optional:

```
^(?|(\w+\s*:)\s*(\W\d+)|(\W\d+))
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/iJ9tC7/2)

It will give **2 capturing groups** for `price: $200` but **only one capturing group** for `$200` as input.

Comment: @NickGinanto: Check my updated regex, I think this is what you need looking at all your comments.